# iphone dev getting video thumbnail (frame) from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone

every one i am trying to get the video frame or thumbnail from a video url but not succeeding in it, here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    thumbnailimg = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ec9KXrpYvzk"]];
    //UIImage *singleFrameImage = [movie thumbnailImageAtTime:10 
                                                 //timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
    //thumbnailimg.image = singleFrameImage;

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification:) 
               name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification
             object:movie];
    NSNumber * time =[NSNumber numberWithInt:10];


    NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:time,nil];
    [movie requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:times timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];



    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void)handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{

        NSDictionary *userinfo = [note userInfo];
        NSMutableDictionary *event = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSError* value = [userinfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailErrorKey];
        if (value!=nil)
        {

            [event setObject:[value description] forKey:@"error"];
        }
        else 
        {

            UIImage *image = [userinfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
            thumbnailimg.image = image;

        }
        [event setObject:[userinfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailTimeKey] forKey:@"time"];


}
```

even the handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification is not firing, plz. tell me what i am doing wrong and how to correct it, thanx in advance, Regards Saad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to read videos from YouTube with a MPMoviePlayerController try to use an other video (from a m3u8 playlist or MP4 file).

Comment: Thanx Julien but i have you tube video links and my requirement is that i have to display video title plus its thumbnail in a table view cell n when user tap it i will play the video, so plz. tell me if there is any work around for this

Comment: Take a look to the YouTube Web Services you may find a solution. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc?hl=fr#Retrieving_Playlist_Contents

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to tell that times should be provided as float, not int.
Replacing:

```
NSNumber * time =[NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
```

with:

```
NSNumber * time =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f];
```

Will maybe fix something.

Similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870972