# Generating thumbnail from video - ios7

Tags: objective-c, video, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, thumbnails

I am using this for reference: [Getting thumbnail from a video url or data in IPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027285/1145339)

The method is using the MPMoviePlayerController class instead of the AVFoundation, and I think I want to use that as well because the people said that MPMoviePlayer way is faster than the AVFoundation way.

The problem is, the method used to create the thumbnails, `[player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame]` is deprecated in iOS 7.0.

By looking at the apple docs, the remaining supported ways to create thumbnails are by the methods `(void)requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:(NSArray *)playbackTimes timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option` and `(void)cancelAllThumbnailImageRequests`. But, as the method signatures dictate, these methods return nothing. So how do I access the `UIImage` thumbnail created by these methods?

If it helps, this is what I have so far in terms of code:

```
    self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];

    //Create thumbnail image
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.videoURL];
    [player requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:@[@1] timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
   //UIImage *thumbnail = ???
```

How do I get a UIImage reference to the thumbnail?

**EDIT**
I figured out how to create a notification for the thumbnail image request (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297726/cant-get-multiple-images-from-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller-osstatus-12) as reference). However, I realise that this method works asynchronously from the main thread, and so my notification handler method doesn't seem to ever be called.

This is what I have now.

```
    self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.videoURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification object:player];
    [player requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:@[@1] timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

And then my handler method:

```
-(void)handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userinfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSError* value = [userinfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailErrorKey];
if (value != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating video thumbnail image. Details: %@", [value debugDescription]);
}
else
{
    UIImage *thumbnail = [userinfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
}
```

But the handler never gets called (or so it appears).

Answer (score 15):

Try this way.

```
import AVFoundation framework
```

in *.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in *.m

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:self.urlForConevW options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generateImg = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
NSError *error = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 65);
CGImageRef refImg = [generateImg copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&error];
NSLog(@"error==%@, Refimage==%@", error, refImg);

UIImage *FrameImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:refImg];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a code to make a thumbnail of the video and save the images to the DocumentDirectory..**

```
//pass the video_path to NSURL
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strVideoPath];

AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

//Set the time and size of thumbnail for image
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(425,355);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;

CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:thumbTime actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *thumbnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];

//And you can save the image to the DocumentDirectory
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);

//Path for the documentDirectory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[data writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your URL is to an HTTP live stream, then it won't return anything, per the docs.  For a file URL, I found that I had to start the request after playing the movie, or it would never get called.